# reverse mathematics strength of "Lipschitz functions are somewhere differentiable"

Tags: reverse-math, real-analysis, lo.logic

What is the [reverse mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) strength of

"For all [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) functions $\; f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \;$, $\;$ there exists a real number $x$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $x$." ?

(defined using epsilon-delta, so not requiring that there exist a function witnessing the convergence)

Since Lipschitz functions are differentiable almost everywhere,

I would guess the answer is "is equivalent to WWKL$_0$ (over RCA$_0$)".

Comment: Are you just looking for a lower bound, or an upper bound too? Did you check whether the "standard" proof works in $\mathsf{WWKL}_0$?

Comment: I'm looking for both a lower bound and an upper bound. $\;$ I couldn't find the "standard" proof anywhere.

Comment: You should probably add the "logic" tag, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Update: I made my answer clearer and also fixed the references and added more.)

Your theorem should be true in every $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ as follows. The following paper

- Brattka, Miller and Nies. *Randomness and Differentiability*.  Submitted.  ([preprint](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/370127/papers/randomnessanalysisjuly_2011.pdf))

proves that every computable function on $[0,1]$ that is Lipschitz is differentiable on all computable randoms.  Further, from this proof, I believe you can extract a single computable martingale $M$ such that if $x$ is a point of differentiability of $f$, then $M$ does not succeed on $x$.  Unlike ML randomness---which corresponds to $\mathsf{WWKL}_0$---with a test for computable randomness, i.e. the computable martingale $M$, you can compute a real $y$ such that $M$ doesn't succeed on $y$.

> Hence there is (I believe) a real $y$
>   computable from the function $f$ for which $f$ is
>   differentiable at $x$.
>
> Hence your theorem holds in every $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$.
>
> This implies that your theorem
>   is true in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ or $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ plus some first order principle.

I should mention, I learned of this trick from Steve Simpson (in the case of Schnorr randomness).

Of course to see if it is provable in ${RCA}_0$, you should check that level of induction/collection used. A recent paper with Jeremy Avigad and Ed Dean,

- Avigad, Dean and Rute. *Algorithmic
  Randomness, reverse mathematics, and
  the dominated convergence theorem*. Submitted ([preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0775))

gives an example where the dominated convergence thereom, in a sense, corresponds to $2$-randomness, but the reverse math strength of the dominated convergence thereom was a bit higher, since $\Sigma^0_2$ collection was needed.

(You do not not seem to need this, but...) even though you know a point $x$ such that $f$ is differentiable, that doesn't mean you know what the derviative is at that point. Actually, you can't even compute the derivative $f'$ in the $L^1$ norm.

There are more published and unpublished works related to the diffentiability of computable functions.  One good summary of the recent work in this area is the Logic Blog on [Andre Nies's website](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~nies/). Another is this [talk](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/370127/talks/RandomnessComputableAnalysisNies.pdf) by Nies.

There are also three results in preparation that may be of value.  I proved, as did Pathak, Rojas and Simpson independently, that the Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds on Schnorr randoms.  In particular this implies that a more restrictive notion of computable Lipschitz function is differentiable on Schnorr randoms (see Nies' talk mentioned above). Freer, Kjos-Hanssen and Nies, have a paper in preparation about Lipschitz functions and differentiability, which in a sense, "reverses" the above results. (Again, this is mentioned in the talk by Nies.)

Comment: Is "that test" [$\hspace{.01 in} f$ being differentiable at $x$] or [the martingale]?

Comment: By test I meant the martingale.  It is computable from the function.  If f is differentiable at x, then it cannot succeed on the martingale.  There may be a null set of differentiable points that succeed on the martingale as well.

Comment: "If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then it cannot succeed on the martingale." $\hspace{2 in}$ ... except for a null set of points $f$ is differentiable at?

Comment: Sorry, I said the converse!  Let me try to say it correct this time.  

As you know, the set of non-differentiable points of $f$ is null.  From $f$ we can compute a martingale $M$ such that if $f$ is *not* differentiable at $x$, then $M$ succeeds on $x$.  (I said "$x$ succeeds on the martingale" before but that was incorrect terminology---the martingale succeeds on $x$.)

Now, since we can compute from $M$ some $y$ on which $M$ does not succeed, we can also computed a real for which $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Do you know a link to "Brattka, Miller and Nies, Randomness and Differentiability"? $\;$ I can't find it online.

Comment: Ricky, see Joe Miller's page - http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jmiller/downloads.html

Comment: (Jason, you may want to rewrite your citations. The second looks like it might have been authored by someone named Dean R. Avigad.)

Comment: The paper I linked to in the post is newer than the version on Miller's site.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is, the newest version

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/370127/papers/randomnessanalysisjuly_2011.pdf

What jason says is right, even for nondecreasing functions. It is in our paper, Subection 5.1

Hence there is (I believe) a real $y$ computable from the function $f$ for which $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Hence your theorem holds in every $\omega$-model of RCA<sub>0</sub>.

This implies that your theorem is true in RCA<sub>0</sub> or RCA<sub>0</sub> plus some first order principle.

Not sure what these fo principles do, I guess it's standard stuff?

Comment: Dear Andre, Welcome to MO! You can use tex-style math as you normally would. The site also uses markdown, which is very useful has some weird side effects from time to time.

Comment: Andre, I suspect that the theorem goes through in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$, but I would need to walk through the proof carefully to be sure.

In case you or another reader is unfamiliar with Reverse Math, the axioms of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ are basically the Peano axioms but with only induction on $\Sigma_1$ formulas (with second order parameters).  Also there is a comprehension axiom for $\Delta_1$ formulas (with parameters).  This comprehension axiom ensures the existence of computable sets.  (.../...)

Comment: (.../...) It is a common mistake (that I have made in the past) to assume that if a set existence principle (like the one asked about) is computable, then it is provable in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$. A common example is the infinite pigeon-hole principle.  Given a computable coloring, an infinite homogeneous set is computable: pick the correct color (by guessing correctly) and enumerate the set.  But to prove it, one needs $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$, a collection principle between $\Sigma_1$ induction and $\Sigma_2$ induction.

Comment: And yes, this is standard reverse math stuff.  The standard resource is Steve Simpson's book Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic.  The first chapter is online at Steve's website:

http://www.math.psu.edu/simpson/sosoa/chapter1.pdf